# How to render a vue component with TR as the root element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I don't have much experience with Vue and facing an issue with redering a component with root as TR element.

I read this in the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats and tried adding the component using `is` property, but that didn't help either.
Check the code below.

```js
Vue.component('car',{
  props: ['number']
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr is='car' inline-template number='123'>
      <tr>
         <td>car no</td>
         <td>{{number}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
    
    <tr is='car' inline-template number='456'>
      <tr>
         <td>car no</td>
         <td>{{number}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

This errors out:
Error compiling template:
Inline-template components must have exactly one child element.

How can I fix this? Appreciate the help.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8d65gvua/

Update ----
More findings

If i wrap my tr in a template it works

```html
<tr is='car' inline-template number='456'>
  <template>
  <tr>
    <td>car no</td>
    <td>{{number}}</td>
  </tr>
  <template>
</tr>
```

I have no clue why. Shouldn't the issue with tr be fixed with using the `is` property? Why do we need to do this?

Comment: Seems like [this has been an issue since 2016](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/error-inline-template-components-must-have-exactly-one-child-element/1729/9)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `inline-template` before, my guess is that you are using it to pass the number to your "inner template"? You can achieve the same thing by using slots. ([Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots))

I did a test but using slots instead, which I think it's a better way to cater for passing "inner templates". Also given the below warning in the documentation with regards to `inline-template` I would opt for slots.

> However, `inline-template` makes the scope of your templates harder to
> reason about. As a best practice, prefer defining templates inside the
> component using the `template option` or in a `<template>` element in a
> `.vue` file.

**Example**

```
Vue.component('my-row', {
    template: `
        <tr>
          <slot></slot>
        </tr>
    `
})
```

The above is a component to define a single table row. The `<slot>` element is basically a placeholder for any content you want to pass into this template.

**Usage**

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr
      is="my-row"
      v-for="todo in todos"
    >
      <td>{{ todo.text }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What will happen here is that `<td>{{ todo.text}}</td>` will be placed instead of the `<slot>` element in the `my-row` component. You can have multiple `<td>` elements, whatever content you put in the `my-row` will appear instead of `<slot>`.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x793nub6

**PS: Slots!**

I don't want to make the answer too long, but keep in mind that with slots you can have a super customisable components, of course this all depends on your needs. But I would suggest having a look at the documentation and trying out a few expirements.

---

**Update - If you still want to use `inline-template`**

I went through the JS Fiddle you shared once more and realised what's the issue you are having. Basically vue is saying that one child needs to be passed. I guess there's some mixup since there's a `<tr>` nested in another `<tr>`. To fix it wrap the inner `<tr>` with a `<template>` element.

**From:**

```
<tr is='car' inline-template number='123'>
  <tr>
    <td>car no</td>
    <td>{{number}}</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

**To:**

```
<tr is='car' inline-template number='456'
  <template>
    <tr>
      <td>car no</td>
      <td>{{number}}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</tr>
```